# Exclude pattern from regex doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, regex-negation

For tokenizer I need regex that matches everything till special symbol `|` or pattern `p[1-4]`.

My best attempt is `^[.*[^\|(p[1-4])]]+`, tested it online for Java and got results I need, but on Android it just always excludes single numbers (1-4).

Example:

`"text2 | p1"` - here instead of `text2` I get just `text`

What is a way to exclude a pattern?

Comment: Give us example of string you want to regex.

Comment: @comrade thanks, added an example

Answer (score 0):

How about is this?

```
^[^|]+?(?=\||p[1-4])
```

Comment: nope, it matches the whole substring "| p2 | p3 |p4)"

Comment: still nothing, it matches "p1 "

Comment: @ab.helly Updated again.

Comment: doesn't match "test2", but still matches "p1"